# Концепция ООП php

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

Как правильно реализовать?

```
class Order{
  public $id;
  public $ProductList;
}
class ProductList{
  public $Order;
  public $Product;
  public $quantity;
}
class Product{
  public $id;
  public $name;
  public $Category;
  public $Price;
}
class Category{
  public $id;
  public $name;
  public $noAmount;
}
class Price{
  public $id;
  public $priceWithDiscount;
  public $priceWithoutDiscount;
}
```

Например мне нужно получить массив заказов Order. Как реализовать заполнение всех вложенных объектов? Все объекты храняться в отдельных таблицах БД, связаны по ИД. Писать один запрос и при обходе создавать все объекты?

Comment: Эх. Я бы на вашем месте немного больше бы подумал над структурой. Ведь создавать класс под список продуктов и отдельно под продукт - бессмысленно как-то. Ведь список продуктов это есть продукт, только не один. А так как разные (почему-то) поля - то я  рекомендовал бы вам почитать о паттернах проектирования и интерфейсах.

Comment: Чего, у productList будут свои методы, которые неприменимы к одному продукту. И все же, если мне нужно заполнить именно такую структуру?

Comment: неправильная структура.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я подозреваю, автор хотел получить несколько более подкрепленный фидбэк, нежели "неправильная структура"

Comment: Все же, как будет правильно?  Писать один запрос и при обходе создавать все объекты или в конструкторе объекта заполнять вложеные объекты при создании?

Comment: @АртемКолос, о том, как грамотно это реализовать рассказывает не одна глава ряда классических книг, например PoEAA. А вы просите ответ, что называется в "двух словах". Если вкратце -- используйте нормальную ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что у Вас, действительно, не очень правильная структура. Как минимум от классов ProductList и Price можно отказаться. Я бы предложил вот такую структуру:

```
class Product {

    public $id;
    public $name;
    /**
     * 
     * @var Category 
     */
    public $category;
    public $priceWithDiscount;
    public $priceWithoutDiscount;

}

class Category {

    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $noAmount;

}


class Order{
  public $id;
  /**
   * Массив объектов Product
   * @var array() 
   */
  public $productList;
}
```

Ну а массив объектов Order получал по каким-нибудь параметрам.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product 
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $category;
    public $discount;
    public $price;

    public function getRealPrice()
    {
        return $this->discount 
            ? $this->discount->calculate($this->realPrice)
            : $this->realPrice;
    }
}
```

Т.е. есть отдельный объект скидки, который мы можем назначить в любой момент. В зависимости от него, будет меняться реальная цена.

```
class Category
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $noAmount;
}
```

Тут без изменений.

```
class Order implements Countable, Iterator
{
      public $id;
      /**
       * Массив объектов Product
       * @var array() 
       */
      $productList;

      public function getTotalPrice()
      {
          // подсчет общей стоимости 
      }

      /*
         Реализация интерфейсов
       */
}
```

Здесь список товаров как в ответе @S.Pronin, но нужно сделать эту объектную модель итерируемой и Countable (если это возможно), тогда можно будет писать что-то такое `count($order)`, или `foreach($order as $product)`

И, наконец, скидка:

```
class Discount
{
    public $id;
    public $discount;

    public function calculate($price)
    {
        return $price - $price * $this->discount; //например, скидка 15%, тогда $discount должен быть 0.15
    }
}
```

Такая модель скидки, подходит, например, для скидок типа "Распротажа - все по 50%", тогда назначается один объект для всех товаров, и можно очень просто поменять M% на N%. Конечно, если у каждого товара своя уникальная скидка - этот способ не совсем подходит.